# Python `requirements.txt` and `setup.py` pick several ranges for the same package

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py, requirements.txt

I am developing 2 packages, package `A` that depends on package `B`. I am currently restricting the versioning of package `B<2.0,>1.7` in the `requirements.txt` and `setup.py` of package `A` which works just fine.

The thing is that I have a way to publish internal beta versions with the version numbering `0.0bx` where `x` is a random number. Is there a way to add a restriction to support this type of beta format? I tried setting `B<2.0,>1.7,<0.1` but it produces the error `ERROR: Cannot install -r /requirements.txt (line 1) and B==0.0b111 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies`?

Comment: Why not create an alpha (or beta) version of `B 1.7`? Wouldn't that work? You would need to install with [the `--pre` flag of `pip install`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-pre), I think.

Comment: What does the version of `B` have to do with your beta versions of `A`? Presumably, you would just use separate versions of `setup.py` for your betas, specifying whatever *they* need, without worrying about what the production version uses. (You are using a version-control system like `git`, `svn`, `hg`, etc, right?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that you are publishing B with

> version numbering 0.0bx where x is a random number

yet you also explain that that version numbering
scheme is causing you interoperability grief.

Consider adopting [SemVer](https://semver.org/) instead.
You don't *have* to externally publish
each of the minor / patch revs that
you make available internally.
There are advantages to using internal
version numbers that are compatible with
external ones.
We have a version numbering scheme,
it addresses certain use cases,
and it serves both internal / external users.
A scheme that doesn't meet current
needs is one that is not fit for use.

Suppose you cut a 3.2.1 release for
external consumption.
You might append a component and use 3.2.1.1
internally, or even append multiple components.
Some folks put a date or build number
into such components.
Then strip them upon releasing 3.2.2 or 3.3.0 or 4.0.0.